# Как установить bolt в unity 2021 на mac m1

Tags: unity3d

Во всех видеоуроках под виндовс запускается установщик bolt, когда я устанавливаю на mac этот установщик даже не скачивается. Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пре перезагрузке unity открылся установщик все заработало.